# Any way to hide group totals in AG Grid Pivot Table

Tags: pivot-table, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm looking to hide the number in parentheses in the [AG Grid pivot tables](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/pivoting/). It's confusing in many cases and I don't see any option to get rid of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `suppressCount` to true in `autoGroupColumnDef` like so:

```
  const autoGroupColumnDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      minWidth: 250,
      cellRendererParams: {
        suppressCount: true
      }
    };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-packages-forked-xrsxym).